# XPath Getting child elements from html

Tags: xpath

I am trying to find the xpath for only the child of a navigation bar. The path which I am trying at the moment is `//div[@class='navCol subMenus']` from this peace of HTML.

```
<div class="PrimaryNavigationContainer">
<div class="PrimaryNavigation">   
    <div class="Menu">   
        <div>    
        <a href="http://www.blah.co.uk/brands.aspx" class="unselectable"><span>Brands</span></a>
     <div class="navCol">
     <div>
         <a class="NoLink unselectable"><span>Shop by Brand</span></a>
         <div class="navCol subMenus">
         <div>                  
      <a href="http://www.blah.co.uk/blah/catlist_bd4.htm" class="unselectable"><span>blah</span></a>
```

I have tried a number of Xpath syntax but none seem to work to bring up just the sub categories. Thank you for any help which you can provide.

Comment: `//div[@class='navCol subMenus']` is correct XPath, is it working? Are you getting any exception?

Comment: I am parsing the html using the html agility pack, and it is not being brought up when I run the application. I am guessing there is a issue with the code and not the x path. Thank you for the help

Comment: You don't close any of your `div` elements...

Comment: Are you able to select other elements on the page? Mb you have an issue with Html Agility Pack...?

Comment: I am able to select the parent of that particular html by using the xpath //div[@class='Menu']/div/a[@class='unselectable']. I am going to have a look through the code now, I through would double check the xpath given I am not great at them.